# ReactNative ScrollView doesnt work properly for different platforms

Tags: react-native

In my app I used ScrollView and on my Android Phone(Redmi Note 7) it works as it should, I can scroll only when keybord is open and elemnts are under the keybord. But on the IOS device (IPhone 5S) screen can be scrolled even when keyboard isnt opened.I even dont know what is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your elements in ScrollView are longer than the screen height size?
You can check the element is over the screen by clicking Cmd+D Show Inspector and clicking bottom of the view.

Comment: I'm using expo and test app on real devices. 
It was the first thing that came to mind, but it seems that the elements are no longer than the screen height size

Answer (score 0):

Set your scrollview style to flex:1 then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

We have essay  way just use `KeyboardAvoidingView` on render ex:
I hope works well.[docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview)

```
   <ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
   <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
      {content}
   </KeyboardAvoidingView>
   </ScrollView>
```